# Is Ulam's theorem equivalent to Sierpiński's theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Ulam's theorem is stated on page 25, Measure and Category(2ed), John Oxtoby, as:

> A finite measure $\mu$ defined for all subsets of $X$ of power less than the least weakly inaccessible cardinal vanishes identically if it equals zero for every one-element  subset.

I saw Sierpiński's theorem in [an answer of MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85837/can-we-put-a-probability-measure-on-every-sigma-algebra).

> If $μ:{\mathcal {P(Ω)}}→[0,1]$ is a probability measure and $|Ω|$ is smaller than the first weakly-inaccessible cardinal, then there must be a countable $A⊆Ω$ such that $μ(A)=1$.

I don't have a reference on the second theorem, though I saw it has been mentioned several times on this site. It seems to me they're telling the same thing.

Sierpiński's theorem must assume every singleton is assigned with a measure of zero execpt for countable many of singletons in $\Omega$, or it can't be a finite measure. Let $A$ be a countable subset of $Ω$ which is the union of all singletons with non-zero measure, Ulam's theorem imply that $Ω \setminus A$ must "vanishes identically". Thus the probability measure must concentrate on $A$. The reverse reasoning is more or less the same.

Probably I misunderstood something obvious, otherwise they can't be named after by two Polish mathematicians who seem to know each other well.

Comment: In Sierpiński's setting, not all singletons have measure zero: Otherwise, since measures are $\sigma$-additive, we would have that $\mu(A)=0$ as well.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: They are both equivalent to $1=1$ hence by transitivity they are equivalent to each other.